# How to increment version number in a shell script?

Tags: bash, wine

The following simple version control script is meant to find the last version number of a given file, increment it, run a given command with the newly created file (e.g., editor), and after that save it to stable. Since it's simple, it doesn't check anything since the script would be modified as needed. For instance, if the result won't be stable, the user can omit the last argument.

However, one major concern of the current functionality is how to implement the following: if the last section after dot has two digits, inc untill 99; if only 1, then inc until 9, then move to the previous section. The versions may have any positive integer number of sections.

```
1.2.3.44 -> 1.2.3.45
1.2.3.9 -> 1.2.4.0
1.2.3 -> 1.2.4
9 -> 10
```

The remaining issue is that it doesn't wait for a tabbed wine editor to close the file; the goal is to detect when the tab is closed. Also, could you explain how best to make sure that my variable names don't overwrite existing ones?

You can also offer other improvements.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Tested on bash 4.1.5
#All arguments in order: "folder with file" "file pattern" cmd [stable name]
folder="$1"
file_pattern="$2"
cmd="$3"
stable="$4"

cd "$folder"
last_version=$(ls --format=single-column --almost-all | \
    grep "$file_pattern" | \
    sed -nr 's/^[^0-9]*(([0-9]+\.)*[0-9]+).*/\1/p' | \
    sort -Vu | \
    tail -n 1)
last_version_file=$(ls --format=single-column --almost-all | \
    grep "$file_pattern" | \
    grep $last_version | \
    tail -n 1) #tail -n 1 is only needed to get 1 line if there are backup files with the same version number
new_version=$(echo $last_version | \
    gawk -F"." '{$NF+=1}{print $0RT}' OFS="." ORS="") #increments last section indefinitely
new_version_file=$(echo "$last_version_file" | \
    sed -r "s/$last_version/$new_version/")
cp "$last_version_file" "$new_version_file"
"$cmd" "$new_version_file" & \
    wait #works with gedit but not with wine tabbed editor
[[ "$stable" ]] && \
    cp "$new_version_file" "$stable" #True if the length of string is non-zero.
```

Update:
The following works on my pc, I will update it if improvements or solutions to unsolved problems are found:

```
#!/bin/bash
inc()
{
shopt -s extglob
    num=${last_version//./}
    let num++

    re=${last_version//./)(}
    re=${re//[0-9]/.}')'
    re=${re#*)}

    count=${last_version//[0-9]/}
    count=$(wc -c<<<$count)
    out=''
    for ((i=count-1;i>0;i--)) ; do
        out='.\\'$i$out
    done

    sed -r s/$re$/$out/ <<<$num
}

folder="$1"
file_pattern="$2"
cmd="$3"
stable="$4"

cd "$folder"
last_version=$(ls --format=single-column --almost-all | \
    grep "$file_pattern" | \
    sed -nr 's/^[^0-9]*(([0-9]+\.)*[0-9]+).*/\1/p' | \
    sort -Vu | \
    tail -n 1) #--almost-all do not list implied . and ..
last_version_file=$(ls --format=single-column --almost-all | \
    grep "$file_pattern" | \
    grep $last_version | \
    tail -n 1) #tail -n 1 is only needed to get 1 line if there are backup files with the same version number
new_version=$(inc)
new_version_file=$(echo "$last_version_file" | \
    sed -r "s/$last_version/$new_version/")
cp "$last_version_file" "$new_version_file"
"$cmd" "$new_version_file" && \
    wait #works with gedit but not tabbed wine editor
[[ "$stable" ]] && \
    cp "$new_version_file" "$stable" #True if the length of string is non-zero.
```

I appreciate the variety of solutions that have been offered, for they help with gaining a perspective and drawing a comparison.

Comment: i've never used the wine tabbed editor, so can't assist there, but please elaborate on what you mean by '..make sure that my variable names don't overwrite existing ones..' - what is the context of that? special shell variables or vars in your script?

Comment: what about `9.9.9`? Be `9.10.0` or `10.0.0`?

Comment: I meant any tabbed editor run by wine, e.g., Notepad Tabs.

As for folders, I mean if a person uses $folder themselves, e.g., for their editor command: alias edit="$folder\Notepad2" then it might not work properly within this script.

Comment: I think 9.9.9 should go to 10.0.0.

Comment: @nnn I've updated to support `10.0.0`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245293/extract-version-number-from-file-in-shell-script

Comment: Version numbers usually don't behave like decimals, so 9.9.9 should normally increment to 9.9.10. Also, 0.100 > 0.50 > 0.10 > 0.5 > 0.1.

Comment: having a script increasing version number - you need to define which version should be increased: major, minor, maintenance and/or build - as @SeanBurton already wrote, you cannot just increase version number like decimal numbers you can go from 1.2 -> 2.0 or from 1.12 -> 1.13 or from 2.10 -> 2.10.1

Comment: I wrote this script that automates a lot of pre-release steps, including bump version functionality, hope it helps anyone who wants to perform these kind of steps automatically https://github.com/jv-k/bump-version.sh

Answer (score 81):

```
$ echo 1.2.3.4 | awk -F. -v OFS=. 'NF==1{print ++$NF}; NF>1{if(length($NF+1)>length($NF))$(NF-1)++; $NF=sprintf("%0*d", length($NF), ($NF+1)%(10^length($NF))); print}'
1.2.3.5
```

---

```
1.2.3.9  => 1.2.4.0
1.2.3.44 => 1.2.3.45
1.2.3.99 => 1.2.4.00
1.2.3.999=> 1.2.4.000
1.2.9    => 1.3.0
999      => 1000
```

### UPDATE:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN{
    v[1] = "1.2.3.4"
    v[2] = "1.2.3.44"
    v[3] = "1.2.3.99"
    v[4] = "1.2.3"
    v[5] = "9"
    v[6] = "9.9.9.9"
    v[7] = "99.99.99.99"
    v[8] = "99.0.99.99"
    v[9] = ""

    for(i in v)
        printf("#%d: %s => %s\n", i, v[i], inc(v[i])) | "sort | column -t"
}

function inc(s,    a, len1, len2, len3, head, tail)
{
    split(s, a, ".")

    len1 = length(a)
    if(len1==0)
        return -1
    else if(len1==1)
        return s+1

    len2 = length(a[len1])
    len3 = length(a[len1]+1)

    head = join(a, 1, len1-1)
    tail = sprintf("%0*d", len2, (a[len1]+1)%(10^len2))

    if(len2==len3)
        return head "." tail
    else
        return inc(head) "." tail
}

function join(a, x, y,    s)
{
    for(i=x; i<y; i++)
        s = s a[i] "."
    return s a[y]
}
```

---

```
$ chmod +x inc.awk
$ ./inc.awk
#1:  1.2.3.4      =>  1.2.3.5
#2:  1.2.3.44     =>  1.2.3.45
#3:  1.2.3.99     =>  1.2.4.00
#4:  1.2.3        =>  1.2.4
#5:  9            =>  10
#6:  9.9.9.9      =>  10.0.0.0
#7:  99.99.99.99  =>  100.00.00.00
#8:  99.0.99.99   =>  99.1.00.00
#9:  =>           -1
```

Comment: yikes! why have i been ignoring `awk` all these years?

Comment: I tried to test your updated version, but it hangs my pc and never prints anything.

Comment: @nnn Try removing `a,` from `function inc(s,    a, len1, len2, len3, head, tail)`. Can you post the error message?

Comment: @nnn Your awk version is too old.

Comment: Does not work for 00.01.99 => 00.2.00 (and 1.02.00 using updated script). I was expecting 00.02.00.

Comment: For those who want to use standard increment, `9.9.9 => 9.9.10` use this code `echo 9.9.9.9 | awk -F. -v OFS=. 'NF==1{print ++$NF}; NF>1{$NF=sprintf("%0*d", length($NF), ($NF+1)); print}'`

Comment: I'm loving your one-line version but it doesn't work with my awk version (and I can't update it easily) 

`awk: cmd. line:1: %*x formats are not supported`

Do you know how I can bypass this format error keeping the same behavior ? It seems possible regarding the awk [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html) but I can't make it working with you solution.

Comment: facing this too -  awk: cmd. line:1: %*x formats are not supported; use NEXTVERSION=$(echo ${VERSION} | awk -F. -v OFS=. '{$NF++;print}')

Comment: Saved lots of my time

Answer (score 71):

For just incrementing the dewey decimal version:
`awk -F. -v OFS=. '{$NF += 1 ; print}'`

Or in a shell script:

```
NEXTVERSION=$(echo ${VERSION} | awk -F. -v OFS=. '{$NF += 1 ; print}')
```

Comment: For me, this is the best solution as I don't need it to be completely robust or customizable

Comment: This must be an answer!

Comment: Legit. Very legit.

Comment: This didn't work on ubuntu 20.04 `1.2.0` outputs: `1.2.0.`, awk version change or locale specific thing? im not sure I used something else..

Comment: @joshweir little change worked for me. 
NEXTVERSION=$(echo ${VERSION} | awk -F. -v OFS=. '{$NF=$NF+1;print}')

Comment: @vishwadeep-singh Thanks. The previous syntax didn't work with all versions of awk, so I made it similar to your suggestion.

Answer (score 39):

### 1. Only increment the selected part

Usage

```
increment_version 1.39.0 0 # 2.39.0
increment_version 1.39.0 1 # 1.40.0
increment_version 1.39.0 2 # 1.39.1
```

#### Code

```
### Increments the part of the string
## $1: version itself
## $2: number of part: 0 – major, 1 – minor, 2 – patch
increment_version() {
  local delimiter=.
  local array=($(echo "$1" | tr $delimiter '\n'))
  array[$2]=$((array[$2]+1))
  echo $(local IFS=$delimiter ; echo "${array[*]}")
}
```

Simplified version of [@dimpiax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/486718/dimpiax) answer

---

EDIT: I created another version of this script that put zeros on the less important parts if the most important ones are changed. Just note the diferent expected results on the usage part.

### 2. Increment the selected part and put zeros on the subsequent parts

Usage

```
increment_version 1.39.3 0 # 2.0.0
increment_version 1.39.3 1 # 1.40.0
increment_version 1.39.3 2 # 1.39.4
```

```
#!/bin/bash

### Increments the part of the string
## $1: version itself
## $2: number of part: 0 – major, 1 – minor, 2 – patch

increment_version() {
  local delimiter=.
  local array=($(echo "$1" | tr $delimiter '\n'))
  array[$2]=$((array[$2]+1))
  if [ $2 -lt 2 ]; then array[2]=0; fi
  if [ $2 -lt 1 ]; then array[1]=0; fi
  echo $(local IFS=$delimiter ; echo "${array[*]}")
}
```

Comment: Wouah, is the best solution !!

Comment: Hi looks like a great solution, I'm trying to get the output to var, however, it doesn't return anything when running in the terminal -- what am i doing wrong :-/ `./increment.sh increment_version 1.39.0 0`

Comment: @einonsy if you put the function alone inside of increment.sh them you must call it. For simplicity you can just put a call on the last line of the same script like this: increment_version $1 $2
Or you can remove the function and just run it.
For this you must remove all occurrences of the string "local", as they are only supposed to be inside functions.

Comment: @AlanRabello nice job, Alan! Taking the 2nd solution :)

Comment: Often when non-patch versions are bumped the smaller version parts need to be reset to 0: I added in your version a while loop:
`local zeroOutIndex=$((${2} + 1));
  while [ ${zeroOutIndex} -lt ${#array[@]} ] ; do
    array[${zeroOutIndex}]=0;
    zeroOutIndex=$((zeroOutIndex + 1));
  done

`

Answer (score 35):

Here is an even shorter version that also supports a postfix (nice for -SNAPSHOT)

```
$ cat versions
1.2.3.44
1.2.3.9
1.2.3
9
42.2-includes-postfix

$ perl -pe 's/^((\d+\.)*)(\d+)(.*)$/$1.($3+1).$4/e' < versions
1.2.3.45
1.2.3.10
1.2.4
10
42.3-includes-postfix
```

### Explanation

I used regex to capture 3 parts.  The stuff before the last position, the number to increment, and the stuff after.

- `((\d+\.)*)` - stuff of the from 1.1.1.1.1.
- `(\d+)` - the last digit
- `(.*)` - the stuff after the last digit

I then use the e option to allow expressions in the replace part.  Note with the e option \1 becomes a variable $1 and you need to concatenate variables with the dot operator.

- `$1` - the capture group of 1.1.1.1.1.
- `($3+1)` - increment the last digit.  note $2 is used in the sub group of $1 to get the repeated 1.
- `$4` - the stuff after the last digit

Comment: Note 1.2.3.9 becomes 1.2.3.10, NOT 1.2.4.0 as the question requires.  I think that is a bogus requirement and nobody ever wants when versioning.

Answer (score 33):

Here are a couple more flexible options. Both accept a second argument to indicate which position to increment.

#### 1. Simple function

For more predictable input.

```
# Usage: increment_version <version> [<position>]
increment_version() {
 local v=$1
 if [ -z $2 ]; then 
    local rgx='^((?:[0-9]+\.)*)([0-9]+)($)'
 else 
    local rgx='^((?:[0-9]+\.){'$(($2-1))'})([0-9]+)(\.|$)'
    for (( p=`grep -o "\."<<<".$v"|wc -l`; p<$2; p++)); do 
       v+=.0; done; fi
 val=`echo -e "$v" | perl -pe 's/^.*'$rgx'.*$/$2/'`
 echo "$v" | perl -pe s/$rgx.*$'/${1}'`printf %0${#val}s $(($val+1))`/
}

# EXAMPLE   ------------->   # RESULT
increment_version 1          # 2
increment_version 1.0.0      # 1.0.1
increment_version 1 2        # 1.1
increment_version 1.1.1 2    # 1.2
increment_version 00.00.001  # 00.00.002
```

#### 2. Robust function

For use with scripts, or more customizability to apply to various versioning systems.  It could use a couple more options, but as it stands now it works for my projects using the "major.minor[.maintenance[.build]]" version sequences.

```
# Accepts a version string and prints it incremented by one.
# Usage: increment_version <version> [<position>] [<leftmost>]
increment_version() {
   local usage=" USAGE: $FUNCNAME [-l] [-t] <version> [<position>] [<leftmost>]
           -l : remove leading zeros
           -t : drop trailing zeros
    <version> : The version string.
   <position> : Optional. The position (starting with one) of the number 
                within <version> to increment.  If the position does not 
                exist, it will be created.  Defaults to last position.
   <leftmost> : The leftmost position that can be incremented.  If does not
                exist, position will be created.  This right-padding will
                occur even to right of <position>, unless passed the -t flag."

   # Get flags.
   local flag_remove_leading_zeros=0
   local flag_drop_trailing_zeros=0
   while [ "${1:0:1}" == "-" ]; do
      if [ "$1" == "--" ]; then shift; break
      elif [ "$1" == "-l" ]; then flag_remove_leading_zeros=1
      elif [ "$1" == "-t" ]; then flag_drop_trailing_zeros=1
      else echo -e "Invalid flag: ${1}\n$usage"; return 1; fi
      shift; done

   # Get arguments.
   if [ ${#@} -lt 1 ]; then echo "$usage"; return 1; fi
   local v="${1}"             # version string
   local targetPos=${2-last}  # target position
   local minPos=${3-${2-0}}   # minimum position

   # Split version string into array using its periods. 
   local IFSbak; IFSbak=IFS; IFS='.' # IFS restored at end of func to                     
   read -ra v <<< "$v"               #  avoid breaking other scripts.

   # Determine target position.
   if [ "${targetPos}" == "last" ]; then 
      if [ "${minPos}" == "last" ]; then minPos=0; fi
      targetPos=$((${#v[@]}>${minPos}?${#v[@]}:$minPos)); fi
   if [[ ! ${targetPos} -gt 0 ]]; then
      echo -e "Invalid position: '$targetPos'\n$usage"; return 1; fi
   (( targetPos--  )) || true # offset to match array index

   # Make sure minPosition exists.
   while [ ${#v[@]} -lt ${minPos} ]; do v+=("0"); done;

   # Increment target position.
   v[$targetPos]=`printf %0${#v[$targetPos]}d $((10#${v[$targetPos]}+1))`;

   # Remove leading zeros, if -l flag passed.
   if [ $flag_remove_leading_zeros == 1 ]; then
      for (( pos=0; $pos<${#v[@]}; pos++ )); do
         v[$pos]=$((${v[$pos]}*1)); done; fi

   # If targetPosition was not at end of array, reset following positions to
   #   zero (or remove them if -t flag was passed).
   if [[ ${flag_drop_trailing_zeros} -eq "1" ]]; then
        for (( p=$((${#v[@]}-1)); $p>$targetPos; p-- )); do unset v[$p]; done
   else for (( p=$((${#v[@]}-1)); $p>$targetPos; p-- )); do v[$p]=0; done; fi

   echo "${v[*]}"
   IFS=IFSbak
   return 0
}

# EXAMPLE   ------------->   # RESULT
increment_version 1          # 2
increment_version 1 2        # 1.1
increment_version 1 3        # 1.0.1
increment_version 1.0.0      # 1.0.1
increment_version 1.2.3.9    # 1.2.3.10
increment_version 00.00.001  # 00.00.002
increment_version -l 00.001  # 0.2
increment_version 1.1.1.1 2   # 1.2.0.0
increment_version -t 1.1.1 2  # 1.2
increment_version v1.1.3      # v1.1.4
increment_version 1.2.9 2 4     # 1.3.0.0
increment_version -t 1.2.9 2 4  # 1.3
increment_version 1.2.9 last 4  # 1.2.9.1
```

Obviously, this is excessive just to increment a version string.  But I wrote this because I had a need for different types of projects, and because if speed is not an issue, I prefer reusability over tweaking the same code across dozens of scripts.  I guess that's just my object-oriented side leaking into my scripts.

Comment: Big fan of this answer, one thing is that at line 49 "Increment target position" it's incrementing in the wrong base, so it can't increment when the version is 08.

Fix is simple, change the line to the following:
```v[$targetPos]=`printf %0${#v[$targetPos]}d $((10#${v[$targetPos]}+1))`;```

Comment: love it! One note regarding the "simple function" when adding the `<position>`: it drops all trailing versions after the position instead of resetting them to 0, which I think should be the correct behavior. I wish I could change it myself but I can barely read the script as is :)

Answer (score 18):

For the common use case to increase *just the patch version*, keep it clear and simple:

```
$ awk -vFS=. -vOFS=. '{$NF++;print}' <<<1.2.99
1.2.100
```

|  | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `-vFS=.` | Set **F**ield **S**eparator to `.` |
| `-vOFS=.` | Set **O**utput **F**ield **S**eparator to `.` |
| `{$NF++;print}` | Reference last field, increment its value |
| `<<<str` | Send `str` to awk's standard input |

Answer (score 13):

Pure Bash:

```
increment_version ()
{
  declare -a part=( ${1//\./ } )
  declare    new
  declare -i carry=1

  for (( CNTR=${#part[@]}-1; CNTR>=0; CNTR-=1 )); do
    len=${#part[CNTR]}
    new=$((part[CNTR]+carry))
    [ ${#new} -gt $len ] && carry=1 || carry=0
    [ $CNTR -gt 0 ] && part[CNTR]=${new: -len} || part[CNTR]=${new}
  done
  new="${part[*]}"
  echo -e "${new// /.}"
} 

version='1.2.3.44'

increment_version $version
```

result:

```
1.2.3.45
```

The version string is split and stored in the array *part*.
The loop goes from the last to the first part of the version.
The last part will be incremented and possibly cut down to its 
original length. A carry is taken to the next part.

Comment: On my pc, it prints spaces instead of periods, but otherwise it works properly. + it has an explanation.

Comment: Problem mentioned in nnn's comment is fixed.

Comment: @fgm if we use 1.2.9.9 then it shows 1.2.10.0 it should be 1.3.0.0

Comment: @damithH It works correctly for me. Bash/shell version issue?

Answer (score 2):

Tired of bash? Why not try Perl?

```
$ cat versions
1.2.3.44
1.2.3.9
1.2.3
9

$ cat versions | perl -ne 'chomp; print join(".", splice(@{[split/\./,$_]}, 0, -1), map {++$_} pop @{[split/\./,$_]}), "\n";'
1.2.3.45
1.2.3.10
1.2.4
10
```

Not quite in compliance with the requirement, of course.

Comment: (which is to say: `<versions perl -ne ...` would let `perl` read straight from the file, rather than from a FIFO attached to a copy of `cat` that's adding nothing but overhead).

Answer (score 2):

### Usage

```
increment_version 1.39.0 0 # 2.39.0
increment_version 1.39.0 1 # 1.40.0
increment_version 1.39.0 2 # 1.39.1
```

#### Code

```
### Increments the part of the string
## $1: version itself
## $2: number of part: 0 – major, 1 – minor, 2 – patch
increment_version() {
  local delimiter=.
  local array=($(echo "$1" | tr $delimiter '\n'))

  for index in ${!array[@]}; do
    if [ $index -eq $2 ]; then
      local value=array[$index]
      value=$((value+1))
      array[$index]=$value
      break
    fi
  done

  echo $(IFS=$delimiter ; echo "${array[*]}")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Determining a version number for a software project is based on its relative change / functionality / development stage / revision. Consequent increments to the version and revision numbering is ideally a process that should be done by a human. However, not to second-guess your motivation for writing this script, here is my suggestion.

Include some logic in your script that will do exactly what you describe in your requirement

*"...if the last section after dot has two digits, inc until 99; if only 1, then inc until 9 ... "*

Assuming the third position is the development stage number `$dNum` and the fourth (last) position is the revision number `$rNum`:

```
if  [ $(expr length $rNum) = "2" ] ; then 
    if [ $rNum -lt 99 ]; then 
        rNum=$(($rNum + 1))
    else rNum=0
         dNum=$(($dNum + 1)) #some additional logic for $dNum > 9 also needed
    fi
elif [ $(expr length $dNum) = "1" ] ; then
    ...
    ...
fi
```

Perhaps a function will allow the most succinct way of handling all positions (majNum.minNum.dNum.rNum).

You will have to separate the project name and version number components of your filename in your script and then construct the version number with all its positions, and finally reconstruct the filename with something like

```
new_version="$majNum.minNum.$dNum.$rNum"
new_version_file="$old_file.$new_version"
```

Hope that helps and check [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146359/how-to-define-the-version-number-of-a-software) as well as [this wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning) if you want to know more about versioning conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use Python. I think this way it a bit more readable than using plain Bash or Perl.

```
function increase_version() {
    python - "$1" <<EOF
import sys
version = sys.argv[1]
base, _, minor = version.rpartition('.')
print(base + '.' + str(int(minor) + 1))
EOF
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use bash-semver

Increment semantic versioning strings in shell scripts.

```bash
## https://github.com/fmahnke/shell-semver

./increment_version.sh
usage: increment_version.sh [-Mmp] major.minor.patch

./increment_version.sh -p 0.0.0
#0.0.1

./increment_version.sh -m 0.0.3
#0.1.0

./increment_version.sh -M 1.1.15
#2.0.0

./increment_version.sh -Mmp 2.3.4
#3.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using just bash, wc and sed:

```
#! /bin/bash
for v in 1.2.3.44 1.2.3.9 1.2.3 9 1.4.29.9 9.99.9 ; do
    echo -n $v '-> '

    num=${v//./}
    let num++

    re=${v//./)(}
    re=${re//[0-9]/.}')'
    re=${re#*)}

    count=${v//[0-9]/}
    count=$(wc -c<<<$count)
    out=''
    for ((i=count-1;i>0;i--)) ; do
        out='.\'$i$out
    done

    sed -r s/$re$/$out/ <<<$num
done
```

Comment: *grumbles about lack of quoting, and `echo -n` where `printf '%s -> ' "$v"` would have been the more portable option*

Answer (score 0):

The `perl` regex one by @Pyrolistical is pretty neat, but if you don't need postfix support and don't like regular expressions, maybe this simple `perl` one liner will be your style:

```perl
$"=".";@v=split/\./;$v[@v-1]++if@v;$_="@v";
```

And this is how I use it:

```bash
$ cat versions
10.0.5.15
5.2.54
2
$ <versions perl -ple '$"=".";@v=split/\./;$v[@v-1]++if@v;$_="@v";'
10.0.5.16
5.2.55
3
```

... if I don't get your vote for a functional and elegant command, please up vote for "prettiest line noise"