# Need help in sed and awk commands

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a text file with contents:(version.txt)

```
#Project Name: XYZ
#Module Name: ABC
#
#
currentVersion=9.2.04
```

Now I have a shell script as shown below which replaces last line of version.txt to `currentVersion=9.2.05`

script:

```
ls_version=`grep -i currentVersion version.txt | awk '{print $NF}'`
counter=`echo $ls_version | awk -F . '{print $NF}'`
fs_version=`echo $ls_version | awk -F"." -v OFS='.' '{$NF=""; print $0}'`
echo "counter b4 addition: $counter"
counter=`expr ${counter} + 1`
version=`echo ${fs_version}$counter`
echo "ls_version: $ls_version"
echo "fs_version: $fs_version"
echo "counter post addition: $counter"
echo "final version: $version"
sed -i -e "s/\(currentVersion=\).*/\1$version/" version.txt
```

but instead it gives o/p like this:

```
currentVersion=05
currentVersion=05
currentVersion=05
currentVersion=05
currentVersion=05
currentVersion=05
currentVersion=05
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong in this script?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are so many things wrong.... don't pipe grep to awk, don't store the output of awk and then use echo to pipe it to another awk, don't use expr, don't use 'sed -i', use $() instead of backticks.  This is not an exhaustive list.

Comment: I cannot see anything in your final `sed` that would cause the contents of the file to have each line replaced with "currentVersion=05".  To debug this, stop using `sed -i` and show the actual output (eg, what happened to "counter b4 addition"?  Perhaps the code you are running is not the code you are showing), the actual input, and the actual code.

Comment: @William Pursell, thanks for your response. After removing sed -I . I see no change/update in version.txt file.

Comment: code execution: `counter b4 addition: currentVersion=04 ls_version: currentVersion=04 fs_version: empty   counter post addition:05  final version : current_Version=05 (multiple entries)`

Answer (score 1):

Following awk will help you to increase the version in your Input_file.

```
awk -F'.' '/currentVersion/{$3=sprintf("%02d",$3+1)"}"} 1' OFS="."   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
{#Project Name: XYZ
#Module Name: ABC
#
#
currentVersion=9.2.05}
```

Comment: What about counter variable? am I using that as well here?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653126/how-to-increment-version-number-in-a-shell-script), I wrote :

```
 perl -pe 's/^currentVersion=((\d+\.)*)(\d+)(.*)$/$1.(sprintf("%02d", $3+1)).$4/e' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry but I cant use perl here. I need to stick to shell scripting