# Increment version with 1 bash (awk)

Tags: bash, unix

I try to increment a version number that look like this `0.0.1-pre`. I would like to increment the third column. The result should look like this:

```
0.0.2-pre
0.0.3-pre
0.0.4-pre
0.0.5-pre
.........
```

i would like to have something like `echo 0.0.1-pre | awk 'BEGIN{x=0;FS=OFS="."} NF>1{$3=$3+x;x++}1'`

Comment: What should happen with `0.0.9-pre`? `0.0.10-pre` or `0.1.0-pre`?

Comment: Your input is a single version number, but the output should be a list. How long is this list supposed to be? Is there another parameter which specifies the number of steps or an upper version-limit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increment version number in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653126/how-to-increment-version-number-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With brace expansion of `bash`

```
printf '%s\n' 0.0.{2..10}-pre
```

- See the local section of the bash manual `PAGER='less +/^[[:blank:]]*Brace\ Expansion' man bash`

Comment: i would to have something like this `echo 0.0.1-pre | awk 'BEGIN{x=0;FS=OFS="."} NF>1{$3=$3+x;x++}1'`

Comment: i  have fix the problem with the command `printf '%s\n'  "0.0.1-pre" | awk -F '.' '{ printf("%s.%s.%01d-pre\n", $1, $2, $3 + 1) }'`

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a pure bash solution for incrementing the third number (`patch`) of a string containing a version number (in the format `major.minor.patch-release`), try:

```sh
version=0.0.2-pre

release=${version##*-}
major_minor_patch=${version%-*}
major_minor=${major_minor_patch%.*}
patch=${major_minor_patch##*.}

echo old version: $major_minor.$patch-$release
((patch++))
echo new version: $major_minor.$patch-$release
```

The output is:

```
old version: 0.0.2-pre
new version: 0.0.3-pre
```