# create new directory with incremental version using bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting, parameter-expansion

I need to generate new directories in incremental fashion. Below is the folder structure:-

```
1. Dockerfile
2. Makefile
3. manifests
    + 1.0.0
    + 1.0.1
```

I want to fetch the latest version from the existing directories in a variable i.e. **last=1.0.1**, add the value **0.0.1** to **last** to get the next version i.e **next=1.0.2**. So that I can create a new directory using **mkdir manifests/$next**, something like this:-

```
1. Dockerfile
2. Makefile
3. manifests
    + 1.0.0
    + 1.0.1
    + 1.0.2
```

I am able to fetch the directory name with the latest version using the below command:-

```
last=$(find manifests -type d -name '[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*' -printf "%f\n" | sort -V | tail -n 1)
```

How do I add **0.0.1** to the variable, so that **next=1.0.2** something like this:-

```
next=$(($last + 0.0.1))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increment version number in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653126/how-to-increment-version-number-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a function for every increment:

```
#!/bin/bash

next() {
  local l="$1"
  local a="$2"
  local l1 l2 l3 a1 a2 a3

  IFS="." read l1 l2 l3 <<< "$l"
  IFS="." read a1 a2 a3 <<< "$a"
  
  echo "$(($l1+a1)).$(($l2+a2)).$(($l3+a3))"
}

last="1.0.1"
add="0.0.1"

new=$(next "$last" "$add")
echo "$new"
```

Output:

```
1.0.2
```

Comment: Usually when you increment the major, you reset the minor and the patch number to 0. When you increment minor, you reset the patch number to 0 as well.

Comment: @LéaGris: Yes, this is a feature that could be added if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

With plain `bash` and GNU utilities:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd manifests || exit
last=$(printf "%s\n" [0-9]*.*.*[0-9]/ | sort -Vr | head -n 1)
last=${last%?} # Remove the last character, that is, the '/'
[[ -d $last ]] && mkdir "${last%.*}.$(( ${last##*.} + 1))"
```

Run it from the parent directory of `manifests`.
 It finds the latest version by doing a version sort on directories containing at least two dots and beginning and ending with a digit. Then it increments (by one) the part coming after the last dot of the latest version found (it assumes that part is an integer number).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `awk`:

```sh
next=`echo "$last" | awk -F. '{print $1"."$2"."($3+1)}'`
```