# Increment version number, but keep zeroes

Tags: bash, perl

I'm trying to increment version number by .10, but also keep following zeros. Here is what i have:

```
printf '%s\n' '1.00' '1.50' '1.90' | perl -i -pe "s/\K.+/$&+0.1/e"
```

This returns:

```
1.1
1.6
2
```

But i want it to return:

```
1.10
1.60
2.00
```

Any tips on how to achieve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increment version number in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653126/how-to-increment-version-number-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 6):

When people work out how powerful regexes are, they often start using them everywhere - even when they're not the most appropriate tool.

There's no need for a regex here. What you want is `sprintf()`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @vers = qw(1.00 1.50 1.90);

for (@vers) {
  my $newver = sprintf '%.2f', $_ + .1;

  say "$_ -> $newver";
}
```

Output:

```
1.00 -> 1.10
1.50 -> 1.60
1.90 -> 2.00
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all,

```perl
s/\K.+/$&+0.1/e
```

is a really weird way to write

```perl
$_ += 0.1 if length
```

And it can apparently be shortened to

```perl
$_ += 0.1
```

---

Solution:

Replace `-p` and

```perl
s/\K.+/$&+0.1/e
```

with `-n` and

```
printf "%.2f", $_ + 0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ printf '%s\n' '1.00' '1.50' '1.90' |
  awk '{printf "%.2f\n",$0+0.1}'
```

Output:

```
1.10
1.60
2.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also hand it over to zsh. For instance,

```
export v
for v in 1.00 1.50 1.90
do
    zsh -c 'printf %.2f $((v+0.1))'
done
```

respectively, if you need to catch the incremented version in a variable,

```
    new_version=$(zsh -c 'printf %.2f $((v+0.1))')
```

Of course, if you go so far, you could think of writing your whole script in zsh instead of bash.

Answer (score 0):

Plain POSIX shell function:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

newver() {
  version=$1
  major=${version%.*}
  minor=$((${version#*.} + 10))
  if [ $minor -gt 99 ]; then
    minor=0
    major=$((major + 1))
  fi
  printf '%d.%02d\n' $((major)) $((minor))
}

for v in '1.00' '1.50' '1.90'; do
  newver "$v"
done
```

Output:

```
1.10
1.60
2.00
```

Or a one-liner using `bc`:

```sh
for v in 1.00 1.50 1.90;do echo scale=2\;$v+.1|bc;done
```

Comment: The output is not quite what is expected in case of 1.90 -> 2.00

Comment: @MarkoJ now output as you want it